# Simple Integer to string/char in MIPS assembly? Print integer to text file?

Tags: string, file-io, integer, char, mips

Ok so I have an assignment where I have to find and print prime numbers.

I got that already complete, but now I need to print my results to a file.

Long story short, how do i print an integer to a file?

*Long story*

I can print integers and strings to the console, so I have my output like this:

```
1.) 2
2.) 3 
3.) 5
...
```

I can print chars/strings just fine to a file, but all i can print is:

```
.)
.)
.)
....
```

Is there a way to convert or store an intger to a string in MIPS assembly? My assignment is not to do a MIPS version iota, so if there is a simple to just output an integer to file, I'd appreciate any insight.

I've read this page :  [MIPS File I/O Example](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)

So that is how I learned to print strings to file, but i cannot find anything on how to print intgers that are calulated in the program. I've been looking since last night for an easy solution, but it escapes me.

This is the first MIPS assigment, we had to write a c program and then translate it to MIPS assembly, so I don't have too much experience so any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

Here is the part of the code which I would like to work on, as you can see I'm trying to mirror what is desiplayed on the console in a text file. I'm using the MARS MIPS simulator.

```
FOR:
beq $t0, $t1, EndFOR
IF:
jal test_prime
bne $s1, 1, EndIF
addi $s0, $s0, 1        #Increment 'c'.

#Print 'c', the nth counted place of the found Prime Integer.
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall

sw $s0, buffer($0)

li $v0, 15
move $a0, $s7
la $a1, buffer
li $a2, 1
syscall

#Print '.) '
li $v0, 4
la $a0, dotP
syscall

li $v0, 15
move $a0, $s7
la $a1, dotP
li $a2, 3
syscall


#Print the Prime integer, 'i'.
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0
syscall

#Print a New Line.
li $v0, 4
la $a0, newL
syscall

li $v0, 15
move $a0, $s7
la $a1, newL
li $a2, 1
syscall
EndIF:

IF2:
beq $s0, 100, EndFOR        #Once 100 Prime Integers have been found, escape out of the 'For' loop.
EndIF2:             #Not Necessary, but just there to have a complete coding style.

addi $t0, $t0, 1            #Increment 'i'.
j FOR
EndFOR:
```

Answer (score 0):

Assembly is all about appreciating high-level programming. You should try convert integer one by one to character and print them. You can turn this pseudo-code to assembly for this purpose (k is the integer number):

```
while(k){
    char c = 0x03|((k%10)&0x0f);
    push(c);
    k=k/10;
}
while(c=pop()){
    printf("%c",c);
}
```